# OnKeyPressed getting activated in 2 Fragments together

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are 2 fragments as F1 and F2 :
From F1 I am overiding The OnResume for a OnKeyPressed to go to F2 on back pressed. 
Now in F2 I am overiding The OnResume for a OnKeyPressed to close the applicationon back pressed.
But the problem is when I am presseing back button on F1 it is directly closing the app. 
Through logs I noticed that the OnKeyPressed of F2 is also getting activated when I am pressing back button on F1. 
How to correct that.

My code is as follows
F1:

```
@Override


public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


    getView().requestFocus();

    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            System.out.println("back pressed");

            switch (keyCode) {

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                    launchFragment(new F2(), F2.class.getSimpleName());
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

My Code for F2 is as follows:

```
@Override

public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    getView().requestFocus();

    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            System.out.println("Set back pressed");

            switch (keyCode) {

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                    Activity a=getActivity();
                    a.finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle fragment transaction in the parent activity of the fragments.

Here is the example. When adding or replacing fragments always call `addToBackStack(null)`, something like this:

```
MyFragment fragment =  new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
// This will add the framgent to backStack that we will use later to retrieve the fragment
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now handle the backpress events of fragments in  parent activity's `onBackPressed()` in which your adding fragments

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // get the number of fragments added to the backStack
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    switch(count){
        // if count is 0 it means no fragment is added yet
        case 0:
            super.onBackPressed();
            break;
        case 1:
            // handle click of backPress in first fragment here
            // getFragmentManager().popBackStack() will take you to the previous fragment.
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
        case 2:
            // handle click of backPress in second fragment here or
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
        default:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the best and only approach to handle the fragment transactions and onBackPressed events.